# Swift - How to filter multi dimentional Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

I have arrays inside arrays like this;

```
var trucks: [boxes]
var boxes: [items]
var items: [fruits]
```

I want to find "apple" inside the items and keep them inside the trucks array. (I will reload the collectionView and display new filtered sections ...etc)

I tried:

```
let myArray = trucks.boxes

let searchArray = myArray.flatMap {
  $0.items
     .filter {$0.name == "apple"}
}
```

But what I get is the items array.

Comment: As defined, `trucks` is an array of boxes. How is it possible to have a `.boxes` property? The same can be said about `$0.items`. Do include the definitions of the classes/structs that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what your structure of class/struct is but given the following definition the result will contain the boxes that has items with name "apple"

```
struct Truck {
    let boxes: [Box]
}

struct Box {
    let items: [Item]
}

struct Item {
    let name: String
}

let truck = Truck(boxes: [
    Box(items: [Item(name: "Banana")]),
    Box(items: [Item(name: "Apple"), Item(name: "Pear")])
])

let searchArray = truck.boxes
    .filter { box in
        box.items.contains(where: { item in item.name.lowercased() == "apple" })
    }
```

Comment: `box.items.filter { item in item.name.lowercased() == "apple"}.count > 0` is must better expressed as `box.items.contains(where: { item in item.name.lowercased() == "apple"})`

Comment: This code could also benefit from some line breaks and indentation, to break up that long line of nested brackets

Comment: @Alexander Thanks, I agree that `contains` is a better option. I will update with an indented version